# How to get a calculated column based on 2 different column in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

Appreciate for any helps and suggestions. 
I have a table structure as following:-

```
  Date,   Product Code   ,Result ,Schedule  
  Day1,   A              ,0      ,0  
  Day2,   A              ,20     ,100
  Day3,   A              ,200    ,100
```

How can i add a new column [Different] which reset by product code

```
  Date   ,Product Code   ,Result ,Schedule ,Different
  Day1   ,A              ,0      ,0        ,0
  Day2   ,A              ,20     ,100      ,-80
  Day3   ,A              ,200    ,100      ,20
```

Where different = previous's different + result - schedule

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste code below in Home ... Advanced Editor, save, and name it **fnRunningSum**

It will create a function to do a cumultive running total on column named Amount

```
(MyTable as table) =>
let Source = Table.Buffer(MyTable),
MyColumn="Amount",    
TableType = Value.Type(Table.AddColumn(Source, "Cumul", each null, type number)),
Cumulative = List.Skip(List.Accumulate(Table.Column(Source,MyColumn),{0},(cumulative,MyColumn) => cumulative & {List.Last(cumulative) + MyColumn})),
Cumu = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source)&{Cumulative},TableType)
in Cumu
```

Load your data into powerquery, here assumed to be in range Table1. Paste code below in Home ... Advanced Editor...

What it does is (1) add a new column that is Result-Schedule (2) Group on Product Code and cumulative sum the new column (3) Expand to get the columns back

```
letSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Amount", each [Result]-[Schedule]),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom" , {"Product Code"}, {{"AllData", fnRunningSum}}),
#"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "AllData", {"Date", "Result", "Schedule", "Cumul"}, {"Date", "Result", "Schedule", "Different"})
in #"Expanded AllData"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to achieve that with a **Column From Examples**, and type what you want to see in the new column. It usually works fine for me.

Documentation in case you have never used it before:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-add-column-from-example